# How to integrate iis in wix v4?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-10, wix4

I want to make an installer, but IISExtension isn't available for wix4 (IIS v10). Where could I find that iis tag?

[image: IISConfiguration.wxs]

[image: setup.build]

[image: msbuild /t:WIX setup.build]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong iis link. Please check this [Migration](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/4561-migrate-v3-source-code-to-v4/) page.

Fix: Rename `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension` to `http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/iis`